# Do there exist modern expositions of Klein's Icosahedron?

Tags: ho.history-overview, nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, modular-forms, soft-question

Reading [Serre's letter to Gray](http://books.google.de/books?id=4Vm4Lq1WSHgC&pg=RA1-PA722&lpg=RA1-PA722&dq=Jean-Pierre+Serre+%22Extensions+icosaedriques%22&source=bl&ots=CTXk-_vVqx&sig=kFq8FuyhYs7sGPOukgPe8kbQcBY&hl=de&ei=vXwvS8jxApjknAOiwY3PBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CA0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false)
, I wonder if now modern expositions of the themes in [Klein's book](http://digital.library.cornell.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?c=math;cc=math;view=toc;subview=short;idno=03070001)
 exist. Do you know any?

Comment: The link should go to page 550 of the book, presumably.

Comment: Related MO question: [Can the unsolvability of quintics be seen in the geometry of the icosahedron?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/133211/6094).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

"Geometry of the Quintic" is available for free at my website.

Jerry Shurman

Comment: To save other people a few clicks, Jerry's webpage is http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/

Answer (score 16):

I got interested in this subject last year (2011) and just got round to writing up [some notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0955) which I hope may be of use. I also have a python script hosted [here](https://github.com/ocfnash/icosahedral_quintic), which implements Klein's icosahedral solution of the quintic, as well as a brief summary of what it does [here](http://olivernash.org/2012/02/05/on-kleins-icosahedral-solution-of-the-quintic/index.html).

The geometry is easy to summarise: using a radical transformation, a quintic can be put in the form $y^5 + 5\alpha y^2 + 5\beta y + \gamma = 0$. The vector of ordered roots of such a quintic lies on the quadric surface $\sum y_i = \sum y_i^2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$ and the reduced Galois group $A_5$ acts on the two families of lines in this doubly-ruled surface by permuting coordinates. The $A_5$ actions on these families, parameterized by $\mathbb{P}^1$, are equivalent to the action of the group of rotations of an icosahedron on its circumsphere and the quintic thus defines a point in the quotients — the icosahedral invariants of a quintic. Inverting either of these quotients (e.g., using the hypergeometric functions given below) is sufficient to allow us solve quintic (in rational functions).

Here's how it looks for a quintic in the simpler form:
  $$
    y^5 + 5y + \gamma = 0
  $$
  (In fact any quintic can be put in this form using only radical transformations.)

Given such a quintic, set:
  $$
    \nabla = \sqrt{\gamma^4 + 256}\\
    Z = \frac{1}{2\cdot 1728}[2\cdot 1728 + 207\gamma^4 + \gamma^8 - \gamma^2 (81 + \gamma^4)\nabla]\\
    z = \frac{{}_2F_1(\frac{31}{60}, \frac{11}{60}; \frac{6}{5}; Z^{-1})}
         {(1728Z)^{1/5}{}_2F_1(\frac{19}{60}, -\frac{1}{60}; \frac{4}{5}; Z^{-1})}
  $$
  and:
  $$
    f(z) = z(z^{10} + 11z^5 - 1)\\
    H(z) = -(z^{20} + 1) + 228(z^{15} - z^5) - 494z^{10}\\
    T(z) = (z^{30} + 1) + 522(z^{25} - z^5) - 10005(z^{20} + z^{10})\\
    B(z) = -1 - z - 7(z^2 - z^3 + z^5 + z^6) + z^7 - z^8\\
    D(z) = -1 + 2z + 5z^2 + 5z^4 - 2z^5 - z^6
  $$
  Then:
  
  $$
    y = -\gamma\cdot\frac{f(z)}{H(z)/B(z)} -
        \frac{7\gamma^2 + 9\nabla}{2\gamma(\gamma^4 + 648)}
        \cdot\frac{D(z)T(z)}{f(z)^2H(z)/B(z)}
  $$
  
  is a root.

Replacing $z$ with $e^{2\pi\nu i/5}z$ for $\nu=1, 2, 3, 4$ provides all the other roots.

Even in this rather gross explicit form, the link with regular solids is visible:

- The roots of $f, H, T$ are, respectively, the locations of the projection of the vertices, face centres, and edge midpoints of a regular icosahedron onto its circumsphere (once this circumsphere has been identified with the extended complex plane by stereographic projection).
- The roots of the last two polynomials, $B, D$ are, respectively, the locations of the vertices and face centres of a regular cube inscribed in the icosahedron.

Answer (score 12):

I covered Klein's "Lectures on the Icosahedron" in a modern way in my doctoral thesis:

Elliptic Curves and Icosahedral Galois Representations, Stanford University (1999)
http://www.math.purdue.edu/~egoins/notes/thesis.pdf

A much shorter and more direct exposition is my publication in IMRN:

Icosahedral $\mathbb Q$-Curve Extensions, Mathematical Research Letters 10, 205–217 (2003)
http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2003/0010/0002/MRL-2003-0010-0002-00019947.pdf

Answer (score 12):

There is a (german) new edition of Klein's "Vorlesungen über das Ikosaeder ..." by Peter Slodowy (1993) with a large (about 80 pages) section of comments and remarks about new developments.

Answer (score 11):

Chapter 5 of McKean and Moll's "Elliptic Curves" explores the circle of ideas around *Ikosaeder*.I'm not sure if you'd consider this sufficiently "modern" - it's certainly a contemporary book but it doesn't use, say, scheme-theoretic language.

Comment: It looks like our identical answers crossed paths!  You beat me by one minute, so I'll delete my answer.

Comment: lol, you're right - I caught it just before you deleted. Very gallant of you! and hey, in math, every minute counts. :-)

Comment: As an aside to everyone else -- McKean and Moll's book is really beautiful!  I read large chunks of it as an undergraduate, and I still go back to it periodically.

Answer (score 11):

In *Glimpses of algebra and geometry* by Gabor Toth, chapter 25 is devoted to Klein's main result.

Answer (score 5):

There is the outrageously expensive "Geometry of the quintic" by Jerry Shurman, which discusses both Klein and Doyle-McMullen approaches (and then some more).

Comment: "expensive", yes.

Comment: since it's softcover with horrible print quality - yes it is.

Comment: See Jerry Shurman's answer for a link to a free copy ;)

Comment: Re: Dr. Shello - yes, Shurman remarked a few months ago on MO he made the text publicly available. This answer predates his release.

Answer (score 3):

In my PH Thesis work 
http://systembit.es/schwarz.htm

In my papier I have asociatted a Riemann Surface to each Schwarz function triangle.
After that ,I´ve got genus and geometric density of spherical tesselation expresions in a new method.
Then I  see Their Poincare Groups ( of each above Riemann Surfaces) as index normal finite subgroup of  Г(2)  (Thanks to  Modular Function Lambda).
Then I  calculate signature of these fuchisian Groups.
Finally I  see there are only nine ( of  above Riemann Surfaces) more Dihedrical cases.

I think my idea  is a new interpretation of Schwarz  triangles ,  different  one to  the Famous  Schwarz Classification based on 14 Schwarz  triangles +Dihedrical cases.

Alfonso García
alfonso@systembit.es

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at Section 1.6 of *Finite Mobius Groups, Immersion of Spheres, and Moduli*, by Gabor Toth.