# Can Fuchsian functions solve the general equation of degree n?

Tags: ho.history-overview, modular-forms, theta-functions, algebraic-equations

In the classic textbook ***Introduction to the Theory of Equations*** (Conkwright, 1941), on p. 85, the author writes that “the algebraic solution of the general equation of degree ***n*** is impossible if ***n*** is greater than four. By this we mean that it is not possible to find the exact values of the roots of every equation of degree ***n*** (***n*** > 4) by performing upon the coefficients a finite number of additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, and root extractions.”

That proposition is considered proven by the Abel-Ruffini theorem of 1824, as Conkwright surely knew. Tantalizingly, though, he goes on to say – without elaborating – that “the general equation of degree ***n*** has been solved in terms of Fuchsian functions.” And there, it seems, the trail ends. A web search of about an hour has yielded nothing more than various restatements of the problem.

Two questions:

(1) Can anyone state, in a form suitable for reduction to a computer algorithm, a solution or family of solutions of the general equation of degree ***n*** (whether based on Fuchsian functions or not)?

(2) Would your solution(s) yield theoretically exact values, or only converging approximations?

This is my first post to your site, and I apologize in advance if I've overlooked answers right under my nose. These questions have, however, stumped my math department chair. (I’m on loan to him – I normally teach humanities, but I have an engineering background and I was asked to fill in for some math courses.)

Comment: Spitballing here, but aren't the "Fuchsian functions" the same as the solutions to the Fuchsian second-order ODE as presented in http://dlmf.nist.gov/31.14 ? I am at least aware that these solutions to this ODE can degenerate to (generalized) hypergeometric functions, which also have been used in the solution of the general nth-degree equation. The alternative to these generalized hypergeometrics of course are the multivariate theta functions, as Charles Siegel has pointed out.

Comment: I think "Fuchsian functions" is a reference to modular functions and modular forms (possibly meromorphic). Hermite's famous solution for the quintic was described by Felix Klein in "Lectures on the icosahedron" and can be generalized to the sextic, but not to general $n$th degree equation (this is explained in the addenda to the Russian edition, including Serre's letter to Gray). Umemura's solution in theta functions mentioned by Charles works for general $n.$

Comment: Earlier references on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9474/do-there-exist-modern-expositions-of-kleins-icosahedron, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32099/what-is-lagrange-inversion-good-for/32261#32261 Classical theory is carefully explained in Fricke's Algebra, II (in German).

Comment: Wolfram has a nice poster at  
http://library.wolfram.com/examples/quintic/
about the quintic case

Comment: Reposting links mentioned in a previous [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/81024) so that they appear in the "Linked" questions list: [Do there exist modern expositions of Klein's Icosahedron?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/9474) and [Victor Protsak's answer to "What is Lagrange Inversion good for?"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32261)

Answer (score 12):

Fuchsian functions are described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_form)

> (1) Can anyone state, in a form
> suitable for reduction to a computer
> algorithm, a solution or family of
> solutions of the general equation of
> degree n (whether based on Fuchsian
> functions or not)?

I had prepared notes on this topic sometime ago so here goes!  There are three principal ways to solve an algebraic equation of degree n:

1. **Algebraically by using radicals
   in a number field.**  This method
   doesn't work if the Galois group of
   the equation is not solvable, which
   happens for general equations beyond
   degree 4.   *In terms of differential
   equations, the method is analogous to
   integrating by quadrature if the
   Automorphism group(Lie group) is
   solvable.*  For more on this, see [Cox's book on Galois theory](https://dacox.people.amherst.edu/galois.html) and [Gaal's book on Galois theory Sec 4.5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821813757)
2. **Transcendental - by reducing
   equation to some familiar "modular
   equation"** : The genus of the function which is used as the solution generally depends on the degree of the equation.  (See [Hilbert's 13th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_thirteenth_problem)) For degree {2, 3, 4},
   you use trigonometric functions.  For
   degree 5, (use genus 1) elliptic
   functions.  For degree 6, you need
   genus 2 theta functions.  For degree
   7, depending on the Galois group,
   requires hyperelliptic or theta
   functions of genus 3.  Beyond degree
   7, you need to see the Umemura paper
   mentioned by Charles Seigel in his
   answer.  I have omitted some information here but for general computational references, see [Bruce King's book Beyond Quartic.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817637761) and [McKean Moll's book Elliptic Curves Chapter 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521658179)
3. **Solution by complex dynamics** : You
   have to find an iterative map working in a function
   field such that attractor(map)=root(equation).   The Newton-Raphson method
   which we apply for degree 2 and 3
   equations is actually a primitive
   version of this method.  You can see the Julia set for Newton's method on [wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html).  For more of this
   method, see the [papers of Scott
   Crass](https://home.csulb.edu/%7Escrass/math.html) and [Doyle McMullen](https://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoyle/docs/icos/icos/icos.html).  A general reference for the method of complex dynamics is [Shurman's book Geometry of the quintic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471130176).  He illustrates the similarities between this method and the method of adjoining radicals in a number field.  In both cases, you are building an extension over a number/function field.  The number field criterion says that says that splitting field can be constructed if Galois group is solvable while the function field criterion says the that Galois group must be nearly solvable (i.e. nearly solvable implies factor groups must be Mobius groups - rotation groups of the sphere)

Comment: 
I just discovered a previous related question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23094/method-of-finding-roots-of-polynominal-equations-with-arithmetic-operations-and-r

Comment: Reposting the link mentioned in the [previous comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/81026) so that it appears in the "Linked" questions list: [method of finding roots of polynominal equations with arithmetic operations and roots and other functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23094)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Fuchsian functions, but at the end of Mumford's "Tata Lectures on Theta II" there's an article by Hiroshi Umemura which explains how to arrive at exact solutions using theta functions.  Part of it is available on Google Books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=jPFaLY31gwYC&lpg=SA3-PA261&ots=CXuPKsY2YC&dq=hiroshi%2520umemura%2520theta&pg=SA3-PA261#v=onepage&q=hiroshi%2520umemura%2520theta&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

you can see this paper:*on fuchsian difffrential equations reducible to hypergeometric equationsby linear transformations.By Tosihusa kimura.*
http://fe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/FE/Free/vol13/fe13-17.pdf