# Transcendental formulas for roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

It is well known that there is no general formula for the roots of a polynomial of degree $\geq$ 5 solely in terms of arithmetical operations and radicals.

Are there formulas using other kinds of operations or transcendental functions of coefficients? Even just for quintics?

For quintics the question can also be asked as: is there a formula for the roots of $z^5 + a z + 1$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: Cf. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical)

Comment: There is a not too complicated formal power series solution for any polynomial $P(x)$ (that also works  for “pseudo-polynomials”, i.e. with non integer exponents) . The series solution is convergent provided the constant term $P(0)$ is relatively not too large (thus it is a perturbation result)
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation/249098#249098

Comment: An inverse function for a polynomial (e.g., $P$ such that $P(z)^5+P(z)+1=z$) is not something that would qualify as "transcendental", almost by definition.

Comment: See [method of finding roots of polynominal equations with arithmetic operations and roots and other functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23094/15780) *AND* [Are elementary and generalized hypergeometric functions sufficient to express all algebraic numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/582825/13130) *AND* [Can Fuchsian functions solve the general equation of degree n?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35065/15780)

Comment: [This Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302437/is-there-an-analytic-way-of-solving-univariate-polynomial-equations-in-general/3302795#3302795) is relevant.

Comment: There is Felix Klein's icosahedral solution of the quintic. It can be solved using modular and theta functions for example. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0955 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.02358

Comment: For solving the general quintic, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540964/how-to-solve-fifth-degree-equations-by-elliptic-functions and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function.

Comment: Charles Hermite and his solution of the quintic equation.

Comment: My answers in the following threads show that there are no solutions in terms of elementary functions / in the elementary numbers. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727534/roots-for-quintic-equations/4229788#4229788 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828551/polynomials-with-degree-5-solvable-in-elementary-functions/4225322#4225322 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555743/how-do-you-solve-5th-degree-polynomials/4229237#4229237 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291909/closed-form-expression-for-roots-of-a-polynomial/4247401#4247401

Comment: It may be that the simpler [“Prabhakar function”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prabhakar_function) solves the equation

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of such formulas.  For example, for the quintic $z^5-z+a=0$,
the Burmann-Lagrange formula gives
$$z=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty{5k\choose k}\frac{a^{4k+1}}{4k+1}.$$
There are also formulas based on theta-functions; see, for example
H. Umemura, Solution of algebraic equations using theta-constants,
Appendix to the book D. Mumford, Tata Lectures on Theta, vol. II.
They solve algebraic equations of any degree.

Remark. When we are talking of formulas involving infinite processes, like series or integrals, he difference between a "formula" and an "algorithm" essentially disappears. There is a famous algorithm which solves polynomial equations (and many other equations) which is called Newton's method. It gives you faster convergence than most formulas.

Answer (score 5):

A trinomial root, including non-integer powers, can be found by means of the confluent Fox-Wright $_{1}\Psi_{1}$ function, a generalization of the confluent hypergeometric function $_{1}F_{1}$, defined as $$_{1}\Psi_{1}([a,\alpha];[b,\beta];\zeta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma(a+n\alpha)}{\Gamma(b+n\beta)}\frac{\zeta^n}{n!}$$ where $-a-n\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}_0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$. It is convergent for $|\zeta|<|\alpha^{-\alpha}\beta^\beta|$.

For $\gamma>1$ the trinomial equation (some algebra steps can set a general trinomial equation in this form) $$z-\omega z^\gamma-1=0$$ has this closed form root $$z =\,_{1}\Psi_{1}([1,\gamma];[2,\gamma-1];\omega)$$ which can be set as $$z=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{n\gamma}{n-1}\frac{\omega^n}{n}$$ whose convergence region is $|\omega|<|(\gamma-1)^{\gamma-1}\gamma^{-\gamma}|$.  For non integer $\gamma>1$ binomials must be interpreted in terms of $\Gamma$ function.

**References**

Miller A.R., Moskowitz I.S. Reduction of a Class of Fox-Wright Psi Functions for Certain Rational Parameters. Computers Math. Applic. Vol. 30, No. 11, pp. 73-82, (1995). Pergamon

Dzevad Belkic. All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert
series, Bell polynomials and Fox-Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. Journal of Mathematical Chemistry (2019) 57:59-106

**Note**

Wolfram Mathematica 12.3 has incorporated recently Fox-H Function (as an experimental feature). Generalized Fox-Wright Function is a Fox-H's special case.