# How to solve a fifth degree polynomIal

Tags: polynomials, na.numerical-analysis

Charles Hermite have created a method using elliptic functions to solve fifth degree polynomial, to get around the theory of Galois. Can someone explain me it and give a simple example?
Tank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the topic on Quintic Functions in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function)?

Comment: I'm french and on french wikipedia page there is no expilcation and i dont know why i forgot to look one the english one, tank you

Comment: Un français qui ne sait pas écrire le nom de *Galois* ?

Comment: J'etais plus concentré sur le fait de faire une phrase passable en anglais plutôt que d'orthographier Galois correctement. Si cela vous a choqué, j'en suis désolé.

Comment: Par ailleurs, en français, on écrit « un Français ».

Comment: J'étais plus concentré sur le fait de faire une phrase passable en français...

Answer (score 6):

This is described in painful detail [here.](http://library.wolfram.com/examples/quintic/steps.html)

Comment: Tanks for tour help

Comment: The notes I peddled in this answer:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9474/do-there-exist-modern-expositions-of-kleins-icosahedron/87610#87610
may also be of interest and hopefully are less a painful read.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html

Comment: The link in this answer is now dead, but it is still available on the Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20140720011318/http://library.wolfram.com/examples/quintic/steps.html